# Update Manager/Software Centre not working (12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-center, update-manager

I restarted my computer and a little red circle with a horizontal white line appeared. I clicked on it and it asked me to show updates, so I did that. Next, it says this:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ehoover-compholio-precise.list, 
 E:The list of sources could not be read., 
 E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I think asking for workarounds for bugs is not on-topic in here. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug and http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to report the bug, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). On the other hand, asking for workarounds for bugs is not [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) in here.